# Read data from a wav file

Tags: angularjs, audio, decode, wav

I want to read a wav file sample rate and size from its header in Angular.

I am trying to use the Audio context to decode the data but I am unable to make it work.

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

audioCtx.decodeAudioData(uint8Array, function (buffer) {
    //read data                 
})
```

I have an array of bytes but I get an error : parameter 1 is not of type `ArrayBuffer`.Then I convert it to `ArrayBuffer` but still get an error

Any ideas?

Comment: show how you are opening up and reading the wav file to construct the audio buffer

Comment: I receive an array of bytes from my API and then I convert it into an ArrayBuffer with this code:                                                                    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(byteArray.length);                                             
    for(var i = 0; i < uint8Array.length; i++) {
        uint8Array[i] = byteArray[i];
    }